# Toastr Spinner animation

Tags: jquery-animate, reverse, jquery-ui-progressbar

How to make progress-bar reverse animation left to right?

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        toastr.options = {
            'closeButton': true,
            'debug': false,
            'newestOnTop': false,
            'progressBar': false,
            'positionClass': 'toast-top-left',  
            'preventDuplicates': false,
            'showDuration': '1000',
            'hideDuration': '1000',
            'timeOut': '5000',
            'extendedTimeOut': '1000',
            'showEasing': 'swing',
            'hideEasing': 'linear',
            'showMethod': 'fadeIn',
            'hideMethod': 'fadeOut',
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the css class (toast-progress)

.toast-progress {right: 0; left: auto;}